# error while loading maven project into eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-2, m2eclipse

I am using Maven 2.2.0 and Eclipse Juno. I am trying to import one of the existing Maven project into workspace.

I got following error.

```
  Could not calculate build plan:
 Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5



Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: 
Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Then I tried running clean install command.

And the build is successful.

Even after that, I am facing same error.

Can any one help me the solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: well, it complains about amissing plugin. So have you tried fetching it from the corresponding repository the usual way ?

Comment: I actually copied the .m2 repository, not fetched as usual due to server problem.

Comment: @kellogs. I have copied it from remote machine directly. I did not download it as usual. I checked my pom.xml just now, there I cannot find any artifact with id <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>.

Comment: I believe "maven-resources-plugin" is the thingyou ought to download from the maven repos

Comment: The above messages is only an excerpt, cause usually maven prints out more information and in particular about downloaded/downloading etc. ? (I recommend an update to Maven 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just got solution to this question.

Added `<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>`

As I see 2.5 folder already exist in .m2 repository, so added this to stop downloading from repository again.

In eclipse--`window--pref--maven--check the path for settings.xml`. Its should be valid path.

It resolved my problem.