# Spring-Maven Project Building error

Tags: maven, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am creating a new project using spring and maven, i am using spring source tool. I have created spring web maven project. the pom.xml created as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples.service.service</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringWeb</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<other part is removed>
```

the eclipse shows red mark at ***0.0.xsd">*** of project tag.
while building project eclipse gives error as follows

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Maven Project Builder' on project 'SpringWeb'.
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5
```

I am not getting what is the error. whether pom.xml file is configured correctly or not. i checked on internet the configuration is right.

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14065872/error-while-loading-maven-project-into-eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very little information that you've provided, it would at least be good to see your maven resources plugin configuration in your pom.xml

But in general it might be that you're using some proxy and while downloading the plugin jar you've received an HTTP error response in HTML format which got saved as a jar in your repo.

Try removing the jar from repo manually and run the build again.